# How to execute raw sql statement for SQL server from django?

Tags: python, django, django-database, django-mssql

Original db query that works:

```
SELECT *
FROM [db_name].[dbo].[table]
WHERE name IN (
SELECT name
FROM [db_name].[dbo].[table]
WHERE active = 1
Group by name
Having count(*) > 1
)
order by name
```

and when I try to execute it from django as

```
from django.db import connection

def fetch_matching_pn_products():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT *"
                        "FROM db_name.dbo.table"
                        "WHERE name IN ("
                        "SELECT name"
                        "FROM db_name.dbo.table"
                        "WHERE active = 1"
                        "Group by name"
                        "Having count(*) > 1"
                        ")"
                        "order by name")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    return data
```

returns this error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '.'. (102)")
```

I have also tried changing `db_name.dbo.table` in django to `[db_name].[dbo].[table]` and `table` with no success.
What needs to be changed so the raw query executes correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a space after each `"`.

Without a space the string contains `SELECT nameFROM` etc., which is incorrect, because FROM should be a separate word.

Answer (score 0):

Why didnt you concatenate it, you can re-write to something like this, check below

```
from django.db import connection

def fetch_matching_pn_products():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db_name.dbo.table \
                        WHERE name IN (SELECT name\
                        FROM db_name.dbo.table WHERE active = 1\
                        Group by name Having count(*) > 1)\
                        order by name')
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    return data
```

refer to this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/